# iPhone view uiorientation not working after changing the viewcontroller

Tags: iphone

I have 2 view controllers, when the app is in the firstview the orignal view the  uiorientation works fine but when I swtch the view and come back to the first view the uiorientation doesn't work. I tried to make the firstview becmefirstresponder but no luck.

What can I do to fix thus issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implementing the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method in your view controller?

For example, for a landscape orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra line to your Info.plist:

Key:UIInterfaceOrientation  Value:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

then only this will start working.

Hope this helps.